# PEAR MIME html table from data base only sending one row

Tags: php, html, email, pear, mime

I am trying to populate an html table in an email from mysql table. The issue I'm having is the table in the email is only displaying the last result. I'm not sure on how to have more than one result display in the html email table.

**Initialize the variables for email**

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblUnitMaster WHERE JobNumber = '" . $JobNumber . "'";
$result=$conn->query($sql);
while ($row=$result->fetch_array())
    {
    $UnitID = $row[0];
    $JobCode = $row[5];
    $RTU = $row[17];
    $ModelNumber = $row[2];
    $SerialNumber = $row[3];
    $Scope = $row[4];
    }
```

**Email String**

```
require 'Mail.php';
require 'Mail/mime.php';

$to = '$FUSER';

$headers['From'] = 'forest@fisenusa.net';
$headers['Subject'] = $JobNumber . " Job Handoff";

// create MIME object
$mime = new Mail_mime;

// add body parts
$html = '<html><body><p>Job: '  . $JobNumber . ' has been handed off from sales. Priority set as ' . $PriorityCode . ' .</p>
<p>Please review and assign an <a href="http://fisenusa.net/pm/pmAssignEngineer2.php?JobNumber=' . $JobNumber. '"> Engineer </a>  as soon as possible.</p>

<table border=2 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=10>

<tr>
<th><b><font color=STEELBLUE size=3>Unit Number</font></b></th>
<th><b><font color=STEELBLUE size=3>Job Code</font></b></th>
<th><b><font color=STEELBLUE size=3>RTU</font></b></th>
<th><b><font color=STEELBLUE size=3>Model Number</font></b></th>
<th><b><font color=STEELBLUE size=3>Scope</font></b></th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><font color=DIMGRAY size=2>' . $UnitID . '</font></td>
<td><font color=DIMGRAY size=2>' . $JobCode . '</font></td>
<td><font color=DIMGRAY size=2>' . $RTU . '</font></td>
<td><font color=DIMGRAY size=2>' . $ModelNumber . '</font></td>
<td><font color=DIMGRAY size=2>' . $Scope . '</font></td>
</tr>   

</table>

<p>Click link to vist master record of Job Number: <a href="http://fisenusa.net/pm/pmUnitMaster2.php?JobNumber=' . $JobNumber. '">' . $JobNumber . '</a></p>

<p>Thank You,</p>
<p>FOREST</p>
<p>' . $quote . '</p>
</body></html>';

$mime->setHTMLBody($html);

// get MIME formatted message headers and body
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);
$body = $mime->get();

$message =& Mail::factory('mail');
$message->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

Answer (score 1):

First step. You should agregate data to array. For example

```
$data = array();
while ($row=$result->fetch_array())
{
    $data[] = array(
        'UnitID' => $row[0],
        'JobCode' => $row[5],
        'RTU' => $row[17],
        'ModelNumber' => $row[2],
        'SerialNumber' => $row[3],
        'Scope' => $row[4],
    );
}
```

second step you concatenation string in loop, for example:

```
     foreach ($data as $row) {
        $html .= 
        '<tr>
        <td><font color=DIMGRAY size=2>' . $row['UnitID'] . '</font></td>
        <td><font color=DIMGRAY size=2>' . $row['JobCode'] . '</font></td>
        <td><font color=DIMGRAY size=2>' . $row['RTU'] . '</font></td>
        <td><font color=DIMGRAY size=2>' . $row['ModelNumber'] . '</font></td>
        <td><font color=DIMGRAY size=2>' . $row['Scope'] . '</font></td>
        </tr>';

}
```

Comment: After trying your suggestion. i know get php Notice: Undefined index: for all of them. Before I was at least getting the last row of the table.

Comment: I went another way. Thanks though.